# Are there any pre-written libraries/software to store and visualize point clouds?

Tags: 3d, compression, visualization

I'm currently working on a motion capture 3d-scanning system, and I am generating a bunch of point clouds, each of which are somewhere between 9megs/file (storing around 600k points, with 4 integers, x-y-z-intensity, for each point).

The cameras are capturing at 60 frames per second and currently, we are looking to capture something like 3 minutes of video, so that'll end up being something close to 100 gigs per video file.

There are two objectives we have with this data. Less importantly, we would like to see if there is anything we can do to compress the data losslessly. More importantly though, we would like to be able to visualize this data on the computer at a somewhat decent frame-rate (hopefully with all the rotating and zooming goodness, but it would okay with just a set camera angle).

The main concerns with this is loading a large data set into memory and how to manage all this, creating a simple GUI, and visualizing the points themselves.

I think I could write something that does a decent job at this, but I don't really want to reinvent the (square) wheel, and since I don't have any experience with this, I would ask you guys for some suggestions (languages, libraries, frameworks etc).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not aware of any kind of software that does this, but if you do it yourself, perhaps it might be a good idea (since this is only a visualization tool) to restrict your data set. Perhaps decrease the number of points rendered (take every other point), decrease the frame rate, or ignore movement of points if the change in position does not meet a particular threshold.

Comment: Do you think I should just attempt to do a surface reconstruction before attempting to do visualizations? I'm kind of worried about poor reconstruction and artifacts though...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... [VTK](http://vtk.org) for visualization; you'll get all the interactivity you want, and 600K points doesn't sound like too much on a decent GPU (even a 4-year old NVidia 7 series or equivalent ATI should handle it).

As for lossless compression, I'd suggest using a binary format for your data and then just zipping it up (say, using zlib or something).